# Draw rectangle with javascript in an image

Tags: javascript, html

I have Html/Css/Javascript Code that make rectangle into an image , everything goes looking good! but when use onmousemove event for create rectangle my function goes crazy !
in this script if you point somewhere in image it draw a rectangle for you if clicked it will be fixed and if use escape key all cleared.
the problem is when I use on mouse move event the rectangle sometime good sometime point another place!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>CSS Units px/in test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    </head>


    <body>

        <style>
            .wrapper {
                position:relative;
            }

            .boxOnImage {
                display: none;
                position:absolute;
                border:2px solid #ff6666;
                background-color:transparent
            }

        </style>

        <div id="imageMeasurement" class="wrapper">
            <img id="innerImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg"/>
            <div id="boxOnImage" class="boxOnImage"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function () {
                var xs = -1;
                var ys = -1;
                var xe = -1;
                var ye = -1;
                var imageMeasurement = document.getElementById("imageMeasurement");
                var box = document.getElementById("boxOnImage");
                function isInImage(x, y) {
                    var innerImage = document.getElementById("innerImage");

                    if (innerImage.offsetHeight < y || innerImage.offsetWidth < x) {
                        return false
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                imageMeasurement.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                    var x = e.offsetX;
                    var y = e.offsetY;
                    if (isInImage(x, y)) {
                        if ((xe == -1 && ye == -1) && (xs != -1 && ys != -1)) {
                            createRectangleOnImage(xs, x, ys, y);
                        }
                    }

                });
                imageMeasurement.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    var x = e.offsetX;
                    var y = e.offsetY;
                    if (isInImage(x, y)) {

                        if (xs == -1 && ys == -1) {
                            xs = x;
                            ys = y;
                        } else if (xe == -1 && ye == -1) {
                            xe = x;
                            ye = y;
                            createRectangleOnImage(xs, xe, ys, ye);
                        } else {
                            xe = x;
                            ye = y;
                            createRectangleOnImage(xs, xe, ys, ye);
                        }
                    }

                });
                document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
                    //27 escape key Code!
                    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                        xs = -1;
                        ys = -1;
                        xe = -1;
                        ye = -1;
                        removeRectangleOnImage();
                    }
                });
                function createRectangleOnImage(xs, xe, ys, ye) {
                    if (box.style.display != 'block') {
                        box.style.display = 'block';
                    }

                    var top = 0;
                    var left = 0;
                    var width = 0;
                    var height = 0;
                    if (ys > ye) {
                        height = (ys - ye);
                        top = ye;
                    } else {
                        height = (ye - ys);
                        top = ys;
                    }
                    if (xs > xe) {
                        width = (xs - xe);
                        left = xe;
                    } else {
                        width = (xe - xs);
                        left = xs;
                    }

                    box.style.top = Number(top) + "px";
                    box.style.left = Number(left) + "px";
                    box.style.width = Number(width) + "px";
                    box.style.height = Number(height) + "px";

                }
                function removeRectangleOnImage() {
                    box.style.display = "none";
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `<canvas>`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial